# Image puzzle game

Tags: javascript, html

*Edited to include entire code* I found this cool image puzzle creator at [here][1] but I can't figure out how to adapt it so that upon clicking a "New Puzzle button" it changes the image to start a new puzzle? My first thought was creating an array??? Not sure, still very new to JS. Any help is appreciated.

```js
window.onload = onReady;  
  
var can;  
var ctx;          
var img;  
var clickX;  
var clickY;  
var selected1;  
var selected2;        
var blockSize   = 160;  
var piecesArray = new Array();  
  
function onReady()  
{  
    can = document.getElementById('myCanvas');  
  
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') >= 0 || !can.getContext)  
    {  
        can.style.display = 'none';  
        document.getElementById('sorry').style.display = 'inline';  
        return;  
    }  
  
    ctx        = can.getContext('2d');            
    img        = new Image();  
    img.onload = onImage1Load;  
    img.src    = "cat.jpg";           
}  
function onImage1Load()  
{  
    var r;  
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)  
    {  
        for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)  
        {  
            r = new Rectangle(i * blockSize, j * blockSize, i*blockSize + blockSize, j * blockSize + blockSize);  
            piecesArray.push(r);  
        }                 
    }  
              
    scrambleArray(piecesArray, 30);  
    drawImage();  
}  
function Rectangle(left, top, right, bottom)  
{  
    this.left = left;  
    this.top  = top;  
    this.right = right;  
    this.bottom = bottom;  
              
    this.width = right - left;  
    this.height = bottom - top;  
}  
function scrambleArray(ar, times)  
{  
    var count = 0;  
    var temp;  
    var index1;  
    var index2;  
  
    while(count < times)  
    {  
        index1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*piecesArray.length);  
        index2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*piecesArray.length);  
                  
        temp = piecesArray[index1];  
        piecesArray[index1] = piecesArray[index2];  
        piecesArray[index2] = temp;  
                  
        count++;  
    }  
}  
function drawImage()  
{  
    var r;  
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++)  
    {  
        for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)  
        {  
            r = piecesArray[i*3+j];                   
            ctx.drawImage(img, r.left, r.top, r.width, r.height, i*blockSize, j*blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);  
        }  
    }  
}  
function highlightRect(drawX, drawY)  
{  
    ctx.beginPath();  
    ctx.moveTo(drawX, drawY);  
    ctx.lineTo(drawX + blockSize, drawY);  
    ctx.lineTo(drawX + blockSize, drawY + blockSize);  
    ctx.lineTo(drawX, drawY + blockSize);  
    ctx.lineTo(drawX, drawY);  
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;  
  
    // set line color  
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";  
    ctx.stroke();  
}  
          
function swapRects(r1, r2)  
{  
    var index1;  
    var index2;  
    var temp = r1;  
              
    index1 = piecesArray.indexOf(r1);  
    index2 = piecesArray.indexOf(r2);  
              
    piecesArray[index1] = r2;  
    piecesArray[index2] = temp;           
}  
function onCanvasClick(evt)  
{  
    clickX = evt.offsetX;  
    clickY = evt.offsetY;  
              
    var drawX         = Math.floor(clickX / blockSize);  
    var drawY         = Math.floor(clickY / blockSize);           
    var index         = drawX * 3 + drawY;            
    var targetRect    = piecesArray[index];  
    var drawHighlight = true;  
              
    drawX *= blockSize;  
    drawY *= blockSize;  
              
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);  
              
    if(selected1 != undefined && selected2 != undefined)  
    {  
        selected1 = selected2 = undefined;  
    }  
              
    if(selected1 == undefined)  
    {  
        selected1 = targetRect;  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        selected2 = targetRect;  
        swapRects(selected1, selected2);  
        drawHighlight = false;  
    }  
              
    drawImage();  
              
    if(drawHighlight)     
        highlightRect(drawX, drawY);  
}
```

```html
<html>  
  
<head>  
  
    <title>HTML5 Puzzle Game</title>  
  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
  
    </script>  
  
</head>  
  
<body style="background-color:#fbfbfb;" >  
  
    <div style="margin:0 auto; width:640px; height:480px; border: 4px solid #cc6699;">  
          
        <img id="sorry" src="sorry.jpg" style="display:none;"/>  
          
       <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="480" onclick="onCanvasClick(event);">  
       </canvas>  
      
    </div>  
  
</body>  
  
</html>
```

Comment: First of all put all code which you have issue. as seen here "img.onload = onImage1Load", where the onImage1Load Function is here??

Comment: And Please read this "http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask"

Comment: Oops sorry, new on here, all code is copied over. Again any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove This from if condition block `navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') >= 0`, It got stucked on firefox. So no need to write this in if condition.

2) As you want a button "New Puzzle button" to replace new image

- `<button id="some id here">New Puzzle button</button>` put this in html below the canvas(or wherever you want).
- bind CLICK event on button using button's ID `document.getElementById("some ID here").onclick = somefunction(){  onReady()  };`
- As you see above the `onReady()` inside of button onclick function.
- Now final thing use Array of images and use `math.random` or `for loop` inside of `onReady function` before `img.src` and assign the value like `imagearray[somenumber here]`.